# Mathcad While Loop

Tags: mathcad

Kindly can anyone guide me about while loop in Mathcad 15.
I have tried many tutorials but wasnt useful.
My while loop is very simple, code is written below.

```
k:=0
x:=8
while k< x
      k <- k+1

k=0    // printing k after while loop, no results were obtained.
```

Answer (score 5):

This should do it.

[image: Mathcad While Loop Help]

You will need to utilise the Programming  menu options, simply add the number of lines your require and include the While construct.  Hope this helps.